# Different version of Jquery Datatable in same page

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working on page that use `Jquery Datatable` Plugin. now i want to use new version of `Datatable` in same page without replacing the old one because it has some dependencies. How is it possible?

Comment: I don't think this is possible

Comment: I'd be afraid to try it (after looking at the plugin code), but you could redefine the name of one of the plugins, say to oldDatatable or something. Essentially you would have two distinct plugins at that point.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Blog](https://datatables.net/blog/DataTables_1.10_beta) entry to Version 1.10 -> section API it is mentioned that he new Version can be initialised with a slightly different syntax.

```
$(function() {
  //Version 1.9.4 -> 1.st Letter is lowercase
  $('#datatable_old').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Filter Data"
    },
    "iDisplayLength": -1,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  });

  //Version 1.10 -> 1.st Letter is uppercase
  $('#datatable_new').DataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Search"
    },
    "iDisplayLength": 5
  });
});
```

This seems to work in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EJrDYdgsUvcHjyk5zy6d?p=preview)

But with everything that is still beta, i wouldn't bet my life on it :-)